# Multiply in while()

Tags: php, while-loop, combinations

I need to multiply variables, but the amount of them is not always the same, is there any function to do so, or how to solve this?

```
$string = "abc";
$amn = strlen($string);
$i = 1;

while ($i <= $amn) {
  $comb[$i] = $i;
  $i++;
}
```

It will save numbers 1, 2, and 3 into variable `$comb[$i]`, and i need to multiply them between each other `$comb[1]*$comb[2]*$comb[3]`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Jan, it would likely be easier to help if you provide a clearer code example.  What are you REALLY trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

there is one function array_sum (http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-sum.php). This sums your array. If you need the product use [array_product](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php).

BR,

TJ

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$product = 1;
while($i <= $amn){
    $product = $product*$i;
    $i++;
}
```

This computes the factorial `n!`, which is `1*2*3*4*5*...*n` (you can leave out the multiplication by one, because it is actually a nop).

You could also use a for loop, to make things more compact:

```
$product = 1;
for($i = 2; $i <= $amn; $product *= $i++);
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all, since you're working with an index, running a loop a given ammount of time, a for loop is more sutable here, it manages the scoping of the index variable `$i` and makes for more readable code.

```
for($i=1;$i<=strlen($str);$i++){
$comb[$i]=$i;
}
```

now to multiply each of them:

```
$product = 1;
foreach($com as $key => $value){
    $product*=$value;
}
```

If what you're trying to do is to just compute a factorial, you don't even need to make an array:

```
function factorial($num){
    $fac = 1;
    for($i=2;$i<=$num){
        $fac*=$i;
    }

}
```

Comment: will the downvoter please tell me why, so that I  can improve?